# 2 returns in one function

Tags: php, function

I would like to return 2 different values with one function. These are my functions:

```
function example1 ($a) {
    return $result1;
    return $result2;
}

function example2 ($edit, $account, $value) {
    $config ($edit);
}
```

Like this I get `$result1` in my `$config`-variable. But what do I need to do to get both returned values in my `example1`-function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the cleanest way to do this:

```
function example1($a)
{
    return array($result1, $result2)
}

// get both values
list($config1, $config2) = example1($a);
```

This will make `$config = $result1` and `$config2 = $result2`.

Comment: Thanks. Out of all the answers, this one was the cleanest! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't return 2 variables in one function, you should return an array instead:

```
function example1 ($a) {
    $result[0] = 'something';
    $result[1] = 'something else';
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Php does not allow for multiple returns from the same function (as python does for example) so if you want to do this you have to either return an array, an object, or redo your logic.

Or redo your logic to return an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

use associative array or stdClass as return variable .

```
function example1 ($a) {
    return array("result_1" => $result1 , "result_2" => $result2 );
}
```

And retreive the values wherever needed.

```
$answer = example1($a);
$firstResult = $answer["result_1"];
$secondResult = $answer["result_2"];
```

Note however that, this will not work :

```
 $firstResult = example1($a)["result_1"] ;
```

and will give a syntax error, due to a shortcoming in PHP. Hence,assign the array first, then retreive the values.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put your results into array and then return said array

```
function example1 ($a) {
    $array = array();
    $array[0] = $result1;
    $array[1] = $result2;
    return $array;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Several solutions:

1. Use arrays : `return array($result1, $result2);`
   You can then use `list($config1, $config2) = $returned;` to get both values assigned to 2 variables.
2. Use references.

   ```
   function example_1($a, &$result2) {
     $result2 = 'whatever';
     return $result1;
   }

   // $config1 will contain $result1
   // $config2 will contain $result2 ('whatever' in this case)
   $config1 = example_1($a, $config_2);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pass-by-reference parameters:

```
function example(&$result1, &$result2) {
  $result1 = 'a';
  $result2 = 123;
}

example($a, $b);
echo "$a, $b";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make more than one return in one function or method. But you have the possibility to return an array with several values instead:

```
function example1 ($a) {
    return array('top' => $result1, 'left' => $result2);
}
```

Now you can access the two values:

```
$result = example1($a);
echo $result['top'] . ' x ' . $result['left'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Return array:

```
function example1 ($a) {
    return array($result1, $result2);
}
```

And use list to retrieve it:

```
list($a, $b) = example1('something');
```